# Can't make my ListView selectable, on press the element doesn't highlight

Tags: android, listview, highlight

Hi I created a ListView extending the ListActivity class, it works all fine but when I click on a item it doesn't get highlighted.

This is how I populate the list:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row_event, null);
    }
    Event ev = items.get(position);

    if (ev != null) {
        //line one
        TextView eventName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.toptext);
        //line two
        TextView eventDate = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.bottomtext);

        if (eventName != null) {
            eventName.setText(ev.getEventName());                            }
        if (eventDate != null){
            eventDate.setText(ev.getEventDate());
        }
    }
return v;
}
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Did you put background to list or list item? If yes - try to remove it and check result.

Comment: So what was the solution? I have no backgrounds and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make sure that the two textviews are set to `android:focusable="false"` so they do not override the listview's focus behavior. Also, the problem may be from setting a background for the textviews. Setting the background for the ListView items overrides the default focus behavior.

Comment: Yes! for some reason the Layout had a background! I removed it and now works (can't believe I waisted so much time on such a stupid problem hehehe). thanks!

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this site:

http://udinic.wordpress.com/2011/07/01/selectablelistview-make-selection-work/